# MY SQL listing all the parent and childrens nodes with a JOIN in MY SQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0, mysql-5.7

I am having a categories table like below
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbPCG.png

and another table called clients_categories
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ertkx.png

clients_categories having only parent categories stored.
I want to list parent categories and their all childrens (n Levels) In a Single query.
Is it possible? Can somebody help?
Expecting results :
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ3B9.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: "n Levels" what is n at most?  there is no good unlimited solution for mysql 5.7, you need mysql 8.  do note that mysql 5.7 has reached end of life and is no longer receiving updates or security fixes; consider it insecure and upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes. you are correct but this is limited to a single parent. I need to pass multiple parent id's . Is there any way?